# Second monitor goes blank after suspend

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, suspend

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with 4.4.0-45-generic kernel. The graphic card is Nvidia GK107GL(Quadro K600). I am using the Nvidia proprietary driver version 367.57. The second monitor goes blank after suspend which is connected via display port. The problem disappears using Nouveau driver but the image quality deteriorates.

I have attached two sys-info screenshot for your consideration. Any advise is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Kind Regards,
Rajib

Comment: image link:      https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1s7O.png